# Are facial 'cleansing' products 'effective' on human skin, and if so, what is their mechanism of action?

Tags: human-biology, skin

All major supermarkets and beauty stores stock some form of facial cleansing products. They come in the form of scrubs, gels, and lotions which vary in application (from in shower, to apply daily without rinsing). Many of these are **not** marketed towards clearing acne or other legitimate dermatological problems. The claims these products make tend to include: reduction of dry/oily skin, neutralizing skin PH levels, and clearing pores. I am unsure if any of these terms are reflective of a real problem, or if the products can even even help said issues.

Therefore, this is a three-part question:

1. Do facial cleansing products actually do what they claim?
2. If so, what is their mechanism of action (i.e., how do the ingredients work)?
3. If not, what do the ingredients in the product actually do to human skin?

Examples of such products and associated claims:

- [Deep Clean® Invigorating Foaming Scrub by Neutrogena](https://www.neutrogena.com/skin/skin-cleansers/deep-clean-invigorating-foaming-scrub/6805021.html)
- [Dr. Alkaitis Organic Purifying Facial Cleanser](https://alkaitis.com/organic-purifying-facial-cleanser/)
- [L'Occitane Aqua Reotier Gel Cleanser](https://au.loccitane.com/aqua-reotier-gel-cleanser,23,1,92224,1224153.htm#s=11851)

Example ingredients from the Neutrogena product above:

> Water, Glycerin, Sodium Laureth Sulfate, Cellulose, Lauryl Glucoside, Acrylates/C10-30 Alkyl Acrylate Crosspolymer, Microcrystalline Cellulose, Phenoxyethanol, Fragrance, Synthetic Wax, Methylparaben, Sodium Hydroxide, Menthol, Disodium EDTA, Polyquaternium-7, Sodium Benzotriazolyl Butylphenol Sulfonate, Ultramarines, Blue 1

Comment: This question is not looking to me to be much of a biology question - I see nothing that asks about *biology*. There are other sites like Skeptics.SE and maybe MedicalSciences.SE but be wary of each of their requirements for a good question.

Comment: This is a medical question (so for MedicalSciencesSE), but I encourage you to first try to find some info from some dermatological website, such as https://dermnetnz.org/ and include it into your question. You can also try to identify active ingredients, like Sodium Laureth Sulfate, and check how they work.

Comment: Welcome Michael. Sorry about the following rant, but I think this question should indeed be migrated as indicated above, but in its current form it cannot be, as it contains three quite independent questions, that are under-researched in my opinion. In other words, each respective question in itself might be too broad. I would advise you to go to Medical Sciences and post a new post over there and take a minute to familiarize yourself with their conventions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to [MedSci.SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users/209/aliced) but cannot be in its current form as there are 3 questions that are very broad as stand-alones in themselves. This question needs work.

Comment: Thank you all, happy to have this closed and I will migrate to appropriate location.  Cheers again for your time. I will note comment regarding three questions, though I do feel that they are interlinked with the original. As I honestly know nothing, I can't really ask "how they work" if they don't work, right?

Comment: @Jan thank you for the link! Much appreciated.

Comment: You can elegantly merge all questions into one, for example: Are such cleansing products more beneficial for the skin health (reduction of dry/oily skin, neutralizing skin PH levels, clearing pores) than regular soap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do facial cleansing products actually do what they claim?

> This dermatologist-tested cleansing gel formula lathers into a bubbly foam removing surface dirt, oil and makeup, while energizing exfoliators sweep away dead skin cells.

So essentially, they are claiming that it is a foaming soap.

Sodium Laureth Sulfate is a detergent, Lauryl glucoside is a surfactant, so it is a good bet that the product is effective as soap. There are a bunch of other compounds that modify how it forms films, so it probably also foams.

### If so, what is their mechanism of action (i.e., how do the ingredients work)?

Similar to any other soap.  They make non-water soluble things on the surface of you skin (such as oil, make up, dead skin cells, etc) more water soluble so that it dissolves when you wash your face.

Some of the other you linked also have moisturizers, so they probably put another oil back in the place of the ones you removed to keep the skin from getting too dry.

> I am unsure if any of these terms are reflective of a real problem, or if the products can even even help said issues.

Or do they work better than normal soap of comparable strength?  Probably not much, although having them labeled as use for your face is nice in that you have a reasonable idea that it won't be too harsh or irritating, whereas if you tried dish soap on your face that might not go so well.